# How do I upload and email a file in a web form?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm trying to create an RMA form and I have everything working except the upload + email attachment.

What I'm trying to do is have the customer upload a scanned copy of their document (in jpeg,gif,png,pdf,word etc formats) but I can't seem to get things going. I'm up on various file upload methods, but I can't seem to figure out where to begin.

This is my php code so far

```
$name=$_POST['first'] ." ".$_POST['last'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$address=$_POST['street'] ." ". $_POST['city'] ."".$_POST['province'] ." ".$_POST['postal'];
$pod=$_POST['pod'];
$sku=$_POST['sku'];
$description=$_POST['description'];
$problem=$_POST['problem'];
$case_id=$_POST['case_id'];
$status=$_POST['status'];
$phone=$_POST['parea'] ."".$_POST['pfirst'] ."".$_POST['plast'];
$tracking=$_POST['tracking'];
$date=$_POST['date'];

$link = mysql_connect('m', 'sk', 's1'); 

if (!$link) 
{

die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
}

mysql_select_db(s);
$status = "Pending";
$tracking = "";
$date = date('c');
$case_id = mt_rand(1252,10000);

while( $fetch = mysql_fetch_array( mysql_query("SELECT `case_id` FROM `webform` WHERE `case_id` = $case_id") ) )
{
$case_id = mt_rand(1252,10000);
}
//$error[] = preg_match('/\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i', $_POST['email']) ? '' : 'INVALID EMAIL ADDRESS';
if(!eregi("^[a-z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-z0-9]+)*" ."@"."([a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+"."\\.[a-z]{2,}"."$",$email )){
$error.="Invalid email address entered";
$errors=1;
}
if($errors==1) echo $error;
else{
$values = array ($name,$phone,$email,$address,$pod,$sku,$description,$problem);
$required = array($name,$phone,$email,$address,$pod,$sku,$description,$problem);

$your_email = "fahad@home.com";
$email_subject = "RMA: ".$case_id;
$email_content = "new message:\n";

foreach($values as $key => $value){
  if(in_array($value,$required)){
    if ($key != $phone && $key != $address) 
    $email_content .= $value.' '.$_POST[$value]."\n";
  }
}

if(@mail($your_email,$email_subject,$email_content,$case_id)) {
    echo 'Request Submitted!<br />';
    echo 'RMA:'. $case_id; 
} else {
    echo 'ERROR!';

}

}

$queries = array ($values, $case_id);
$piece = implode(",",$queries);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `webform` (`case_id`, `name`, `phone`, `email`, `address`, `pod`, `sku`, `description`, `problem`, `status`, `tracking`, `date_recieved`) VALUES ('$case_id', '$name', '$phone', '$email', '$address', '$pod', '$sku','$description', '$problem', '$status', '$tracking', '$date')")

or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close($link);


?>
```

So basically, I'm not sure where to place the file upload section or even how to use it. I have a working html design for it that brings up the file browser and everything, I just don't know how to link that process to the php side, and then after uploading attach that to the email.

Thank you kindly in advance for everyone's help!

Comment: RTFM? http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't.

My company sends millions of emails monthly and email attachments are the biggest single problem that we have.  Bottom line, you attach things and you raise the chances of being blocked or flagged for spam by a significant factor.

Send a link instead.  Use a unique hash identifier in the link that the person can click to initiate a download.  It makes for a smaller email, more spam friendly delivery, easier coding for you, and happier customers.

Comment: alright, sounds great - but how do I do that? I know how to get a file uploaded to the server, but as far as the hash identifier goes I don't have a clue unfortunately.

Comment: There's probably some unique identifier you could use.  Is there an RMA id in the database?  If so, you could base64 encode that number and save it as your filename.  Or, save a randomly generated filename to the RMA database record and build the link that way.  Regardless, you just need to have some sort of unique, non-sequential id that either hits a page that serves up the file or directly points to a file to tell the browser what to download.  I'd personally route my users through a download.php page that would then serve up the file based on the $_REQUEST vars.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. I think what I will do is the way you suggested and force the file name to match the RMA number since it will always be unique, then in email to the recipient i'll have it echo the url+$rmanumber. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

I use this exclusively and it has served me very well.

http://formtoemail.com/